# Rearrange from flat json to tree Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a json which i as datasource for hierarchical Kendo grid.I searched other questions but they compare with parent-id value and arrange. since i dont have such column, does anyone have any idea on how to get the required json or any idea on how to generate the hierarchical grid with current json.

my current json looks like

```
var data=[{
            head:"head1",
            machine:"machine1-1",
            product:"product1-1-1",
            quantity:100
        },
        {
            head:"head1",
            machine:"machine1-1",
            product:"product1-1-2",
            quantity:120
        },
        {
            head:"head1",
            machine:"machine1-2",
            product:"product1-2-1",
            quantity:110
        },
        {
            head:"head2",
            machine:"machine2-1",
            product:"product2-1-1",
            quantity:110
        }];
```

and the required json is

```
var data=[{
            head:"head1",
            Details:[{
                        Allmachines:
                        [{
                            machine:"machine1-1",
                            Allproducts:
                            [{
                                product:"product1-1-1",
                                quantity:100
                            },
                            {
                                product:"product1-1-2",
                                quantity:120
                            }]
                        },
                        {
                            machine:"machine1-2",
                            Allproducts:
                            [{
                                product:"product1-2-1",
                                quantity:110
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
        },
        {
            head:"head2",
            Details:[{
                        Allmachines:
                        [{
                            machine:"machine2-1",
                            Allproducts:
                            [{
                                product:"product2-1-1",
                                quantity:110
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
        }]
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Why downvote? Its just my requirement. I saw all other questions but cannot find solution. Please dont vote. I just need a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a little broad question. I would go by using [**`reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a tree like that.

Here in the snippet, in the first `reduce`, it creates an array that has all the unique `head` present in the input array.

Next, we go for next level and create `Allmachines` property. You can see console for resulting array.

*While following snippet is just half of the solution, I hope it would give a head start and you can achieve expected result from there on.*

```js
var data = [{
    head: "head1",
    machine: "machine1-1",
    product: "product1-1-1",
    quantity: 100
  },
  {
    head: "head1",
    machine: "machine1-1",
    product: "product1-1-2",
    quantity: 120
  },
  {
    head: "head1",
    machine: "machine1-2",
    product: "product1-2-1",
    quantity: 110
  },
  {
    head: "head2",
    machine: "machine2-1",
    product: "product2-1-1",
    quantity: 110
  }
];

var res = data.reduce((arr, obj) => {
  var cur = arr.filter(o => o.head === obj.head)[0]
  if (!cur) {
    arr.push({
      "head": obj.head
    })
  }
  return arr;
}, []);


res = res.reduce((arr, obj) => {
  obj.Details = obj.Details || [{
    Allmachines: []
  }];
  // add machine and product similarly from here on
  return arr;
}, res);

console.log(res)
```